# Nested Expression in Powershell returning part of Expression

Tags: powershell, active-directory, expression

Trying to pull some information from AD through Powershell, Specifically:
samaccountname
First Name
Last Name
Last Logon Date
Password Last Set
Enabled
Password Policy applied

The way that I am proving password policy applied is with Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy, and using the appliesto attribute to show where the user is getting their policy, since we are using fine grain password policies.

```
get-adgroupmember  <Group> -Recursive | %  {get-aduser $_ -properties *}| select samaccountname,givenname,surname,lastlogondate,@{Name='PwdLastSet';Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.PwdLastSet)}},enabled,@{name="MemberOf"; Expression={  $(Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy $_) | select  (@{Expression={ ($_.AppliesTo|%{$_.split(',')[0].substring(3)}) }})}} | OGV
```

This command actually pulls all of the requested information

```
samaccountname givenname  surname lastlogondate        PwdLastSet            enabled MemberOf                                        
-------------- ---------  ------- -------------        ----------            ------- --------                                        
<Account>          <First>     <Last>               <Date> <Date> True       @{ ($_.AppliesTo|%{$_.split(',')[0].substring(3)}) =<Applies to Group>}
```

I am trying to figure out why it's adding that extra bit '@{ ($*.AppliesTo|%{$*.split(',')[0].substring(3)}) =' before showing the resultantpolicy.appliesto.

Comment: Sorry for the wonky formatting in the output - it pulls everything where it needs to be, just adds that extra bit of text - I could just trim the csv afterward, but this is for an artifact and cannot be manually or programmatically altered after it is generated

Comment: Select-Object uses the whole expression as the resulting property name when you otherwise omit a name or label. That being said, you don't need to nest `Select` here: `@{name="MemberOf"; Expression={$(Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy $_).AppliesTo |% { $_.split(',')[0].Substring(3)}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior - if you fail to supply a name or label alongside a calculated expression, `Select-Object` will use the expression's own source code extent as the resulting property name:

```
PS ~> 1 |Select { $_ * 10 }

 $_ * 10
---------
       10

PS ~> Get-Process -Id $PID |Select @{Expression={$_.Name}}

$_.Name
-------
pwsh
```

Skip the nested `Select` pipeline and instead use `ForEach-Object` (alias `%`) to calculate the property value(s) directly:

```
   ... |Select-Object ...,@Name="MemberOf"; Expression={$(Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy $_).AppliesTo |% { $_.Split(',')[0].Substring(3)}}}
```